# Bluetooth using C (BlueZ) on Raspberry pi3 won't write to Android. Read is fine

Tags: android, c, bluetooth, bluez, raspberry-pi3

I researched, and by finding information on this site, thought I had it figured out, but I am still not able to send from the pi to my Android in C.  I am able to receive from the Android fine.  The Android client software seems to be fine, as I am able to communicate both directions by using:

'sdptool add SP' and then 'sudo rfcomm watch hci0'

I then used `minicom -D` using the `/dev/rfcomm0` device.

Before executing this app, I do run the 'sdptool add SP'.  I am able to connect with my Android after this.  I do not get any errors.  I just do not get anything on my Android screen.

What am I missing?  I thought that once I had the socket open, and the connection succeeds, I could read and write from it.

Here is my code on the pi:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_rc loc_addr = { 0 }, rem_addr = { 0 };
    char buf[1024] = { 0 };
    int s, client, bytes_read, status;
    socklen_t opt = sizeof(rem_addr);
    status = 0;

    // allocate socket
    s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

    // bind socket to port 1 of the first available 
    // local bluetooth adapter
    loc_addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    loc_addr.rc_bdaddr = *BDADDR_ANY;
    loc_addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
    bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr));

    // put socket into listening mode
    listen(s, 1);
    printf("Put into listening mode\n");

    // accept one connection  
    client = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_addr, &opt);
    ba2str(&rem_addr.rc_bdaddr, buf);
    fprintf(stderr, "accepted connection from %s\n", buf);

    //write some bytes
    if (status == 0)
        status = write(client,"Hello World",11);
    if (status < 0) printf("Something is broken\n");

    // read data from the client
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    bytes_read = read(client, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if( bytes_read > 0 )
        printf("received\n [%s]\n", buf);

    // close connection
    close(client);
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on this for days.  As soon as I ask the question, I figure it out.  Two things:

1. Make sure your terminal program is not looking for /n/r before it spits out data, or maybe you should just make sure you send a /n/r on your test!
2. The 'int status' holds the number of char sent from the last write command.  If you try to loop (I did for test although not shown in my code here) and only write while status==0, it will only send the first time.  If you set a buffer limit, it might not get reached.

The combination of the two made it look like I was receiving nothing.